# Formatting Multiple Columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe I'm working with that has a large number of columns, and I'm trying to format them as efficiently as possible. I have a bunch of columns that all end in .pct that need to be formatted as percentages, some that end in .cost that need to be formatted as currency, etc.

I know I can do something like this:

```
cost_calc.style.format({'c.somecolumn.cost'       : "${:,.2f}",
                        'c.somecolumn.cost'       : "${:,.2f}",
                        'e.somecolumn.cost'       : "${:,.2f}",
                        'e.somecolumn.cost'       : "${:,.2f}",...
```

and format each column individually, but I was hoping there was a way to do something similar to this:

```
cost_calc.style.format({'*.cost'       : "${:,.2f}",
                        '*.pct'        : "{:,.2%}",...
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first way doesn't seem bad if you can automatically build that dictionary... you can generate a list of all columns fitting the *.cost description with something like

```
costcols = [x for x in df.columns.values if x[-5:] == '.cost']
```

then build your dict like:

```
formatdict = {}
for costcol in costcols: formatdict[costcol] = "${:,.2f}"
```

then as you suggested:

```
cost_calc.style.format(formatdict)
```

You can easily add the .pct cases similarly. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would use regEx with dict generators:

```
import re
mylist = cost_calc.columns

r = re.compile(r'.*cost')
cost_cols = {key: "${:,.2f}" for key in mylist if r.match(key)}

r = re.compile(r'.*pct')
pct_cols = {key: "${:,.2f}" for key in mylist if r.match(key)}

cost_calc.style.format({**cost_cols, **pct_cols})
```

note: code for Python 2.7 and 3 onwards

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

mylist = cost_calc.columns
r = re.compile(r'.*cost')
cost_cols = {key: (lambda x: f'{locale.format_string("%.2f", x, True)} €') for key in mylist if r.match(key)}

r = re.compile(r'.*pct')
pct_cols = {key: "{:.2%}" for key in mylist if r.match(key)}
```

note: version for euro